# Create a list of lists from sliced part of file names in Python 3.x

Tags: python, list

I have some text files with these kind of names in folder

80010867_0698_X_CO_P45_02T_R1
80010867_0698_X_CO_P45_03T_R1
80010867_0698_X_CO_P45_04T_R1
80010867_0698_X_CO_P45_05T_R1

I want to delete some of the files using a criteria that references
part of the file name before I process the files further. The idea is
to make a list of integers from items sliced from the filename.

The part of code of interest

```
path = 'D:\Radio Access\Tools\Atoll\Antenna patterns\pattern\pattern'
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path,'*.msi')): 
    freqcheck = filename[-21:-17]
    f = int(freqcheck)    
    if 698 <= f <= 790:          
        lte700 = []
        lte700.append(f)
        print(lte700)
```

If I run the code I get output like this

```
[698]   [698]   [698]   [698]   [698]   [698]   [698]
```

But what I really want is something like

```
[[698],[698],[698],[698],[698]]
```

I have tried many methods including extend(),sum() but am getting errors to do with 'type int not iterable'.

Comment: Why not `[698, 698, 698, 698, 698]`?

Comment: This will also work, with the output issue resolved I won't need list of lists.

Answer (score 1):

You are clearing the list `lte700 = []` with every file. What you need is to declare it outside of the loop:

```
path = 'D:\Radio Access\Tools\Atoll\Antenna patterns\pattern\pattern'
lte700 = []
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path,'*.msi')): 
    freqcheck = filename[-21:-17]
    f = int(freqcheck)    
    if 698 <= f <= 790:          
        lte700.append(f)
print(lte700)
```

Also, if you REALLY want to have a list of lists (inner lists being with only one item), append a list of the value: `lte700.append([f])`

Answer (score 0):

thing you missed out is,

1) `lte700 = []` defined empty list inside for loop. it should be outside and before for loop.

2) put print statment after forloop

```
path = 'D:\Radio Access\Tools\Atoll\Antenna patterns\pattern\pattern'
lte700 = []
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path,'*.msi')): 
    freqcheck = filename[-21:-17]
    f = int(freqcheck)    
    if 698 <= f <= 790:                      
        lte700.append(f)
print(lte700)
```

so this will gives you,

```
[698, 698, 698, 698, 698]
```

if you want,

```
[[698],[698],[698],[698],[698]]  this means
```

change your append `lte700.append([f])`

Comment: this is what op want.. yes i did

Comment: I think he did read it carefully... He even added the PS after I added it :-)

Comment: i didnt duplicated it. i wrote on my own.. check the timing.. similar answer can repeat in same time which never meant duplicating...  i execute before post. so it took time but posted simutaneously

Comment: Thanks guys, this has got me unstuck!